# Programatically checking files into TFS getting more than expected

Tags: c#, api, tfs, checkin, working-directory

So I have a .NET app which goes thru and generates a series of files, outputs them to a local directory and then determines if it needs to update an existing file or add a new file into a TFS (Team Foundation Server) project.

I have a single workspace on my local machine and there are 10 different working folders that are other coding projects I have worked on from this particular machine.  My problem happens when I go to check if the file already exists in the TFS project and an update is required or if needs to be added to the project as a new file.

snipet:

```
static string TFSProject = @"$/SQLScripts/";
static WorkspaceInfo wsInfo;
static VersionControlServer versionControl;
static string argPath = "E:\\SQLScripts\\";

wsInfo = Workstation.Current.GetLocalWorkspaceInfo(argPath);
TeamFoundationServer tfs = new TeamFoundationServer(wsInfo.ServerUri.AbsoluteUri);
versionControl = (VersionControlServer)tfs.GetService(typeof(VersionControlServer));

Workspace workspace = versionControl.GetWorkspace(wsInfo);
workspace.GetLocalItemForServerItem(TFSProject);
```

At this point I check if the file exists and I do one of two things.  if the file exists, then I mark the file for EDIT and then I writeout the file to the local directory, otherwise I will script the file first and then ADD the file to the workspace.  I dont care if the physical file is identical to the one I am generating as I am doing this as a SAS70 requirement to 'track changes'
If it exists I do:
workspace.PendEdit(filename,RecurisionType.Full);
scriptoutthefile(filename);

or if it doesn't exist
scriptoutthefilename(filename);
workspace.PendAdd(filename,true);

Ok, all of that to get to the problem. When I go to check on pending changes against the PROJECT I get all the pending changes for all of the projects I have on my local machine in the workspace.

```
// Show our pending changes. 
PendingChange[] pendingChanges = workspace.GetPendingChanges();
foreach (PendingChange pendingChange in pendingChanges)
{
    dosomething...
}
```

I thought that by setting the workspace to workspace.GetLocalItemForServerItem(TFSProject) that it would give me ONLY the objects for that particular working folder. 

If there any way to force the workspace object to only deal with a particular working folder?

Did that make any sense?  Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so it turned out that I had a corrupted TFS workspace cache on my machine.
Here was the solution (from a command prompt):

```
SET AppDataTF=%USERPROFILE%\Local Settings\Application Data\Microsoft\Team Foundation
SET AppDataVS=%APPDATA%\Microsoft\VisualStudio
IF EXIST "%AppDataTF%\1.0\Cache" rd /s /q "%AppDataTF%\1.0\Cache" > NUL
IF EXIST "%AppDataTF%\2.0\Cache" rd /s /q "%AppDataTF%\2.0\Cache" > NUL
IF EXIST "%AppDataVS%\8.0\Team Explorer" rd /s /q "%AppDataVS%\8.0\Team Explorer" > NUL
IF EXIST "%AppDataVS%\9.0\Team Explorer" rd /s /q "%AppDataVS%\9.0\Team Explorer" > NUL
```

The other part of the issue is that by having the project folder in the same workspace, it WILL pull in all pending changes from other projects.  I created a secondary workspace with only the SQLScripts project and local folder and everything works like a charm.

Maybe someone else will find this useful...

Answer (score 5):

using LINQ you can get the pending changes of particular folder

```
PendingChange[] pendingChanges = workspace
    .GetPendingChanges()
    .Where(x => x.LocalOrServerFolder.Contains(argPath))
    .ToArray();
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is another way to refresh you workspace cache:

tf workspaces /s:http://SomeTFSServer:8080/

Also, Workspace has a method called UpdateWorkspaceInfoCache(..) that seems to do the same thing. I haven't tested this, though.