# Using the TFS API, filetypes with extensions like .svnExe get ignored

Tags: tfs-sdk

I'm working on a tool which migrates from SVN to TFS using the TFS API.

```
workspace.CheckIn(
     pendingChanges,
     currentUser.TfsUser,
     set.LogMessage + " on " + String.Format("{0:d/M/yyyy HH:mm:ss}", set.TimeStamp) + " by " + currentUser.SvnUser,
     (CheckinNote)null,
     (WorkItemCheckinInfo[])null,
     (PolicyOverrideInfo)null
);
```

This is the way i check my revision in, but sometimes it ignores files like .svnExe, or other "unknown" file types.

Is there a way to check ALL filetypes in TFS?

Comment: Does pendingChanges contain the files you want to CheckIn? Which version of TFS are you using? If you add files to SourceControl in Visual Studio, it filters specific file types, like EXE and DLL, because they are **usually** the output and not necessary for development. Half-OffTopic: Do you plan to publish your tool somewhere? At the moment I just know one tool for SVN->TFS migration and that costs 2000€ per year, but it might be that I need to migrate a SVN in future ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two possibilities that I can think of:

**Possibility 1: Something is causing the PendAdd() to fail.**

For example, if the path already exists in Version Control, you have to use a `PendEdit()` instead.

To diagnose this possibility, you should subscribe to the [VersionControlServer.NonFatalError event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.versioncontrol.client.versioncontrolserver.nonfatalerror.aspx).

**Possibility 2: You could have a corrupt workspace cache**

You can refresh the cache by calling [Workstation.Current.EnsureUpdateWorkspaceInfoCache()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb139685.aspx) or by following the steps in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/917231/11210) (run `tf workspaces /collection:http://yourserver:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection`, or delete the directories manually).